# File Encryption in XCode

Tags: macos, cocoa, encryption

I am new to Mac development.
In my project i need to encrypt files.
Can anybody suggest me the most preferred library in mac environment.
Please help me with sample if possible.

I am developing a cocoa application.

Comment: I was trying to use OpenSSL in my Xcode project. And I saw that apple prefer CDSA. As I told before I am a beginner. I need a guidance from you expert guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, firstly read Apple's ["Cryptographic Services Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/Introduction/Introduction.html) and then become familiar with the ["Common Crypto"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/Common%20Crypto.3cc.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3cc/CommonCrypto) library, which is now preferred over OpenSSL under Cocoa.

Lastly Google for "cocoa common crypto sample" and find gems like [this](http://robnapier.net/blog/aes-commoncrypto-564).